# How can I fix Android import settings after adding your SDK as a module?

Tags: jawbone

Copied from the old forum:

I am trying to access the Jawbone API for the first time so I am following your Android Github steps. I downloaded your SDK and have it added as a module to my project but it is still telling me that it can't find any of the following import settings:

```
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import com.jawbone.upplatformsdk.api.ApiManager;
import com.jawbone.upplatformsdk.api.response.OauthAccessTokenResponse;
import com.jawbone.upplatformsdk.oauth.OauthUtils;
import com.jawbone.upplatformsdk.oauth.OauthWebViewActivity;
import com.jawbone.upplatformsdk.utils.UpPlatformSdkConstants;
```

I also loaded your UpPlatform_Android_SDK-1.0.0 project and HelloUp and they both seem to have the same problem even though one of your suggested ways to get started is to just build off of your HelloUp example.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the project with the latest gradle version and buildtools. It should work now.

Reimport or do a gradle sync after you get the latest source.